# CKEditor initial tweaks - font size

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using CKEditor on a webpage.
Quite impressive but I have few very annoying issues I hope you can help me overtake.

1) When the editor is created by Javascript the default font size (12px, I guess) is too small for my7 needs. I would like the font size to be 18px as the user starts typing on a new document.

2) I can change the font size of a block of text by selecting the block of text and then using the combo for the font size. What I can't do is set the combo for the font size (i.e. to 30px) and then type at that size. I think I can do the latter on Microsoft word, for example.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default styles, then you must change it at:

Providers\HtmlEditorProviders\Fck\FCKeditor\editor\css\fck_editorarea.css

Just change the style:

```
body, td
{
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

Does thi help?

[Source](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/127/postid/168950/scope/posts/Default.aspx)

Comment: No, unfortunately didn't help. I have tried what they said. Probably that is become that is a forum on FCKeditor and the post is 3 years old. Thanks anyway. Any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty easy guys,

open 'ckeditor/content.css', edit this part :

```
.cke_editable
{
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-family:'me_quran' //example font
}
```